# How to copy data in a $scope going inside to a function?

Tags: angularjs, copy

```
$scope.data = {name:"harold", age:"25", address:"california USA",};


 function assignData() {
   $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.data);
 };
```

how can i copy a data in an object into an object inside a function using angular.copy? or any other idea of doing this beside ng-copy? just ignore the data being used lets just assume that the data in $scope.data is too many thats why im finding ways to lessen the codes. thank you soo much

Comment: I didn't understand your question, please clarify it.

Comment: i want to copy the data in the "$scope.data" going to the "$scope.data" inside the function assignData() thanks sir

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: that doesnt work. am i exactly doing it right? @_@

Answer (score 0):

You can use second parameter in copy method like: `angular.copy(source, [destination]);`

Or do let me know what is the exact problem?

Comment: can i copy the a data(source) outside the function?

Answer (score 0):

inner functions has all access to the variables declared in outer function.
like

```
$scope.data = {name:"harold", age:"25", address:"california USA",};
```

create one more variable

```
$scope.data = {name:"harold", age:"25", address:"california USA",};
    $scope.dup_data;


 function assignData() {
   $scope.dup_data = angular.copy($scope.data);
 };
```

Note:
    angular.copy performs only a shallow copy when dealing with objects.so $scope.data and $scope.dup_data pointing to the same object.